# Remove CellWidget from QTableWidget when focus out

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget in which some cells have QComboBox as cellWidget. I want to create the comboBox only when the user clicks in the cell. For this, I have caught itemClicked signal and created the comboBox and set it as cellWidget.

Now, I want to delete this comboBox in two scenarios - if the user selects some value from the comboBox, or the user simply focusses out (click anywhere in the dialog).

For the first case, I have use the signal QComboBox::activated which is invoked when something is selected in the drop-down. There I delete the comboBox and it works fine.

However, I am not sure how to proceed for the second case (delete the comboBox when the user focusses out of the drop-down without selecting anything).

I tried capturing eventFilter for focusOut for the tablewidget as well as the comboBox, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use QItemDelegate for this purpose:

comboboxdelegate.h

```
class ComboBoxDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ComboBoxDelegate(QObject *parent = nullptr) :
        QItemDelegate(parent)
    {
    }

    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
    {
        QComboBox *editor = new QComboBox(parent);

        editor->addItems(QStringList() << "1" << "2" << "3" << "4"); // fill it with your own values
        return editor;
    }

    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
    {
        QString text = index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toString();

        QComboBox *cb = static_cast<QComboBox*>(editor);
        cb->setCurrentText(text);
    }

    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
    {
        QComboBox *cb = static_cast<QComboBox*>(editor);
        QString text = cb->currentText();
        model->setData(index, text, Qt::EditRole);
    }

    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
    {
        editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
    }
};
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
...
ui->tableWidget->setItemDelegate(new ComboBoxDelegate);
...
```